Seeding data in Entity Framework
I'm using Entity Framework to manage a Postgresql database, which has three tables - Products, ProductCategories and ProductImages.
These three tables are related to each other through foreign keys, for example the ProductCategoryId of the Products table is a foreign key to the ProductCategories table, as is the ProductImageId which is a foreign key to the ProductImages table.
Here is the data seeding class:
public static class DbInitializer
{
        public static void Initialize(ProductContext context)
        {
            if (context.Products.Any()
                && context.ProductCategories.Any()
                && context.ProductImages.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }

            var productCategories = new ProductCategory[]
                {
                new ProductCategory
                    {
                        Name = "Tops",
                    },
                new ProductCategory
                    {
                        Name = "Hats",
                    },
                new ProductCategory
                    {
                        Name = "Shoes",
                    },
                //...
            };
            
            // seeding productImages 
            var productImages = new ProductImage[]
                {
                new ProductImage
                    {
                        // Id = 1,
                        Name = "cat-photo_0000.jpg",
                        Description="Wings harness"
                    },
                new ProductImage
                    {
                        // Id = 2,
                        Name = "cat-photo_0001.jpg",
                        Description="Carry Bag Deluxe"
                    },
            };

            // seeding Products
            var products = new Product[]
            {
                new Product
                    {
                        Name = "Angel Wings Harness",
                        Description = "The purrrfect accessory to take your kitty to the next level.",
                        Price = 10,
                    },
                new Product
                    {
                        Name = "Deluxe Carry Bag Orange",
                        Description = "Backpack-style carry bag with dome.",
                        Price = 20,
                    },
            };

        context.Products.AddRange(products);
        context.ProductCategories.AddRange(productCategories);
        context.ProductImages.AddRange(productImages);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

Here are the three entity classes Product, ProductCategories and ProductImages:
public class Product
{
    // [Key]
    // public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductCategory")]
    public int? ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory? ProductCategory { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductImage")]
    public int? ProductImageId { get; set; }
    public ProductImage? ProductImage { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)] // Adjust the maximum length as needed
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductImage
{
    // [Key]
    // public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)] // Adjust the maximum length as needed
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)] // Adjust the maximum length for description
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}

I have seeded some dummy data in the three tables, as you can see the ProductCategoryId and ProductImageId columns got no values (null) in the Products table.



After that, I can post new records from the Swagger page for example:

Now my question is, how can I populate those Id values from ProductCategories and ProductImages table and apply them into the Products table to replace those NULL? Looks like a silly question but just need some helps. Thank you.

When seeding you should specify IDs manually. You have commented some places // Id = 1, it is right way. You should not expect the database to generate them during seeding,  because for generating subsequent migrations, EF Core do not look at database, it uses for comparing IDs which are supplied by developer.

Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv. The reason why I commented out those "Id"s because yes in that way I can insert Id values to the tables, however I will encount 'Id conflict  errors' when I post a new record from the swagger page or postman, on the other hand with my current code which has the Ids generated by database automatically I can post/insert new "product" record withount any issues...

You need to initialise sequences in your database to be higher than seeded data Standard sequence-driven columns
